# SoftLayer: How to get imageId?

Tags: image, import, operating-system, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ssh-keys

I need to get ImageId from the following piece of code, in SoftLayer:

```
import SoftLayer
from pprint import pprint as pp

class example():

def __init__(self):
    self.client = SoftLayer.Client()

def main(self):
    """
    Will reload the operating system with a new imageTemplate, 
    along with a set of sshKeys. This will erease all data.
    """
    # Change these IDs
    imageId = 1234567
    sshKey1 = 123
    sshKey2 = 456
    serverId = 102938
    config = {
        'imageTemplateId': imageId, 
        'sshKeyIds': [sshKey1, sshKey2]
    }

    output = self.client['Hardware_Server'].reloadOperatingSystem('FORCE', config, id=serverId)

    pp(config)
    print "RESULT\n"
    pp(output)

if __name__ == "__main__":
main = example()
main.main()
```

Does anybody know how to get the imageId?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image ids through the control portal page, you just need to see  all private images here https://control.softlayer.com/devices/images

Through API you can use the method SoftLayer_Account::getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups

```
GET https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups
```

And using python it should be something like this:

```
 images = client['SoftLayer_Account'].getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups()
```